# How do I add style to content in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, fonts, coding-style, colors

I have been working in a JavaScript file and my content has been working with phrases. Now I want to change the style of those phrases. The first function (see function swapFE) I want to change the font style of the phrase node to normal. And change the color of the phrase node to the color value (155, 102, 102). The second function (see swapEF) I want to change the font style to italic and the font color to black.  How do I write these? And do I write it within my those functions in JavaScript or do style changes get applied directly within CSS or HTML?

These are the two functions I want to apply the style changes to:

```
    //this function changes the French phrase to an English phrase.
function swapFE(e) {
       var phrase = e.srcElement; 
       //phrase.innerText = english[phrase.id];
    var parent = phrase.parentNode;
    //childNodes[0] is the number of the phrase +1 
    var idnum = parent.childNodes[0];
    //parseInt takes a textstring and extracts it to make a number. Then you will subtract 1 from the number.
    var phrasenum = parseInt(idnum.innerHTML)-1;
    phrase.innerText = english[phrasenum];

  }


function swapEF(e) {
       var phrase = e.srcElement; 
       //phrase.innerText = english[phrase.id];
    var parent = phrase.parentNode;
    var idnum = parent.childNodes[0];
    var phrasenum = parseInt(idnum.innerHTML)-1;
    phrase.innerText = french[phrasenum];
```

If you could even just point me to a reference where I can find these properties that'd be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to add the style changes. By writing parent.childNodes[1].style.fontStyle= "normal" or "italic" (depending on the function); and parent.childNodes[1].style.color = "black".

```
//this function changes the French phrase to an English phrase.
    function swapFE(e) {
           var phrase = e.srcElement; 
           //phrase.innerText = english[phrase.id];
           var parent = phrase.parentNode;
           //childNodes[0] is the number of the phrase +1 
           var idnum = parent.childNodes[0];
           //parseInt takes a textstring and extracts it to make a number. Then you will subtract 1 from the number.

       var phrasenum = parseInt(idnum.innerHTML)-1;
       phrase.innerText = english[phrasenum];
       parent.childNodes[1].style.fontStyle= "normal";
         //Below is the correct way to write an RGB style.
         parent.childNodes[1].style.color = "rgb(155, 102, 102)";
}


function swapEF(e) {
       var phrase = e.srcElement; 
       //phrase.innerText = english[phrase.id];
       var parent = phrase.parentNode;
       var idnum = parent.childNodes[0];
       var phrasenum = parseInt(idnum.innerHTML)-1;
       phrase.innerText = french[phrasenum];
       parent.childNodes[1].style.fontStyle= "italic";
       parent.childNodes[1].style.color= "black";
```

Answer (score 11):

```
obj.style.whicheverProperty = "value"
```

for instance:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.fontVariant = "italic";
```

The google keyword you're looking for is HTML DOM (document object model), which defines the various styles as properties of an object's style member.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just change a class to the element ..

in the swapFE function

```
phrase.className = 'english';
```

and in the swapEF function

```
phrase.className = 'french';
```

and in your css file

```
.english{ color:#9b6666; }
.french{ font-style:italic; color:#000; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `element.style` you can change css from Javascript.

For example:

```
document.getElementById('mydiv').style.backgroundColor = 'red';
```

And to help you find the exact syntax for the attribute, here's [CSS Properties To JavaScript Reference Conversion](http://codepunk.hardwar.org.uk/css2js.htm).

Comment: Do I put this within my function in JavaScript? Because I tried it and it didn't work. Also, if I have multiple style attributes do I create a new document.getElementBy... for each or is there a way to list multiple style attributes in one document.getElementBy...?