# Handling styles in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have json which returns in the format as shown below

```
<p>jellp</p>
```

how can i apply styles using javascript? right now i'm using

```
cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(data['data']['timeline'][i]['content'][j]['title'] ));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add style to content in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170323/how-do-i-add-style-to-content-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.style.{property}` on any DOM node. For example, this would color the text in the paragraph red:

```
var p = document.createTextNode(data['data']['timeline'][i]['content'][j]['title']);
p.style.color = "red";
cell.appendChild(p);
```

Comment: italics, bold and color styles have already been added! i need to display it as it is! but <p> <b> <i> is displaying exactly like it is.

example: <p>this ts a <i>text</i></p>

Comment: @user1450516 Sure, I was just using color as an example. You can apply whichever styles you want, not just color, with `.style.{property}`.

Comment: i don want to apply styles! i jus want to show the content which has  styles already applied!!
document.createTextNode will return json element completely including the style tags. i want to replace the style tag with the actual styles!

Comment: @user1450516 You should ask a new question that clearly describes your actual intention; the question above *does* say that you are wanting to apply styles with Javascript.

Comment: how to handle HTML tags inside javascript?